# Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected (Node.js + MySql) when always using database qualified object references

Tags: mysql, node.js

What I'm trying to achieve is the ability to access tables within two databases by using database qualified table names (without specifically setting the default database with an SQL `USE` statement). My JavaScript application running on Node.js v10.15.3 is connecting to MySql with the NPM mysql 2.17.1 library as follows:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

...

let configuration = {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    user: "user",
    password: "password"
};

let connection = mysql.createConnection(configuration);
```

The connection is made but when I query using database qualified table names

```
let select = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM application.table;';

connection.query(select);
```

I get:

```
(node:20332) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected
```

My guess is that this error was the mysql NPM library detecting that I hadn't specified a database to use, so I tried adding the following before the SELECT statement:

```
connection.query(`USE application;`);
```

...and now I get:

```
(node:10412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'application.application.table' doesn't exist
```

So, the Node `mysql` library appears to be prepending the database name everywhere I reference any database object...

I'm actually storing the database qualified table names as JavaScript strings of the form `'application.table'` or `'metadata.table'` and would prefer to keep these in this format for simplicity of management (e.g. if the design required a table were to move from one database to the other we only need to change the string that references the table in one place).

Is there a Node mysql library configuration option to assure it that all database object references will be database qualified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I needed to escape my query identifiers as follows:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

let connection = mysql.createConnection(configuration);

let select = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ${mysql.escapeId('application.table')};`;

connection.query(select);
```

Here's the documentation [GitHub](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers) or [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers)

While the documentation doesn't specifically cover the case of referencing database qualified tables - using `escapeId()` definitely overcame the error that was generating.

I'd be curious as to the magic that's apparently happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL node package is designed to be used like that:

```js
let configuration = {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "application" // Add database name here
};
```

And you can change database using *changeUser* function, like this:

```js
connection.changeUser({
    database : 'metadata'
}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error in changing database', err);
      return;
    }
    // Do another query
})
```

As far as I know, there's no way to query the database using `database.table` notation using MySQL Node package.

**EDIT:**
I saw something based on your comment.. I think it is be possible to do what you want to do!
Check this out:

```js
var options = {sql: '...', nestTables: '_'};
connection.query(options, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  /* results will be an array like this now:
  [{
    table1_fieldA: '...',
    table1_fieldB: '...',
    table2_fieldA: '...',
    table2_fieldB: '...',
  }, ...]
  */
});
```

It seems like you can pass a delimiter `nestTables` or something like to use table names in queries !

> By default, node-mysql will overwrite colliding column names in the order the columns are received from MySQL, causing some of the received values to be unavailable.
>
> However, you can also specify that you want your columns to be nested below the table name like this

So I guess there's a workaround over here ! Have no more idea, sorry :/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... that implies that t isn't possible to join tables from different databases e.g. `SELECT * FROM a.b AS x, c.d AS y WHERE x.id = y.id;`

Comment: Take a look at my edit! Maybe you can find something there

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - I've figured out a way to get my code working and I posted an answer - perhaps someone might have insight into the "why" I needed to use `escapeId()` for my references, but for now it's good enough that it's working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is more easy:

```js
let configuration = {
    database: "application" //name -> database is required
};
```

Answer (score 1):

all the above answers helped in some way,
but I was able to solve the issue by just using the . operator (database_name.table_name)
database is a collection of tables and tables is a collections of fields.
the err

```
 Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'application.application.table'
```

means it could not access the table name
by just adding .users in my case solved the issue

connection.query(`SELECT * FROM bincom_test.users ORDER BY id DESC`, function(err, rows){

you can check my repo to see how I did mine.
https://github.com/Olabisim/bincom_backend_test

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you resolved you're problem but with mysql2 there is a way to connect to mysql server without selecting a specific DB you can do :

```
const  mysql=require("mysql2");

const {log,table}=console;

sqlServer=mysql.createConnection({
  host:"127.0.0.1",
  user:"user",
  password:"root",
  port:3306
});

sqlServer.connect((err,res)=>{
  log(err,res);
});

//Show the name all of you're db in SQLserver

sqlServer.query("SHOW DATABASES",((err,res)=>{
  //if err
  err?log(err):null;
  table(res);
}));
```